# How to use Mailcore framework in my IOS project?

Tags: xcode, ios

i have download mailcore for iphone from https://bitbucket.org/mronge/mailcore/downloads .i have try to build it shows error as

> No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv6, VALID_ARCHS=i386)

So i can't add this mailcore framework to my ios project .Please help me to find solution

Comment: It seems the architecture you've build the project (or libraries) is wrong. Do you build for the simulator?

Comment: i built for device not for simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Getting Started](https://bitbucket.org/mronge/mailcore/src/d156df4351e7/Resources/GETTING_STARTED.txt) documentation on the project:

> IPHONE USE
>
> MailCore has an included iPhone
>   target, but it requires some
>   additional compiled binaries (OpenSSL
>   and CyrusSSL). I am unable to
>   currently provide these, however the
>   company Remail is offering the
>   binaries and a compiled copy of
>   MailCore for the iPhone. Contact
>   Remail for more information:
>
> mailcore@remail.com

It seems like you'd need to get those before building against the iPhone target.

Comment: thank u so much for info .i have openssl and cyrusssl builds for IOS but still, iam getting those error what to do..!!.any ides??.Actually i have doubt in way to add mailcore to my project .any good  tutorial for add framework ??

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of other searching:

As of Feb 2013, this is no longer an issue. MailCore download includes all libraries you need.

There are two issues I ran into, though, which sent me searching here for answers...

1. You have to have the command line tools installed in Xcode to build. The subprojects under MailCore use them to build themselves. 
   Xcode > preferences > downloads > components tab > Command Line tools must say "installed".
2. Subprojects under MailCore will throw errors about "config.h not found" if your path to MailCore contains a space. I found a closed issue in the github issue discussion stuff abou this. Thus, "/usr/home/me/dev/MailCore" is fine... but "/usr/home/me/dev stuff/MailCore" is not.

For #2, put your MailCore download somewhere where there's no spaces in the path. you can drag the MailCore.xcodeproj into your project to add it no matter where on disk your project is located. Doesn't have to be in the same folder.