# How to add mailcore framework in iphone project

Tags: iphone, mailcore

I have downloaded mailcore for ios but I'm unable to add it to my iphone project.
Any help or pointers would be welcome.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Already asked and answered in [a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4792155/1029106).

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/

remail uses mailcore, and since its acquisition by google, is open source.

Answer (score 0):

GETTING STARTED

The best way to start learning MailCore is by reading through
 documentation intro (in index.html) 
and the the included example
projects. 
To run the example projects:

1. Copy MailCore.framework to your ~/Library/Frameworks folder.
2. In each example project, add ~/Library/Frameworks/MailCore.framework
   to the list of Linked Frameworks.
3. Build it!

The documentation isn't as detailed as I'd like. Sorry about that!